# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream

Tags: vb.net, stream

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream
Can anybody assist my code?

```
Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Dim imSource() As Byte = memStream.GetBuffer
Dim imStatus As Integer = publicStream.Read(imSource, 0, streamLength - 1)
imSource.GetValue(memStream.ReadByte)
```

Comment: And how is memStream created/declared?

Answer (score 1):

Where have you declared and instantiated `memStream`? You would need something like:

```
Dim memStream as MemoryStream = new MemoryStream
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the image or file which you gonna read as stream, In the properties, change the Build Action to Embedded Resource.